# res.redirect() outputs to browser "Found. Redirecting to <url>"

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

I have found the answer to my problem, and it is completely outside the scope of the question I originally asked -- there was actually a line of code intentionally writing this output to the screen. Because stackoverflow does not allow me to delete the question, the original question remains...

I have a node application which works fine in a dev environment, but when I run it locally (with `npm run start`) and when a separate service submits a POST request:

```java
final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

I get this problem:

```js
res.redirect(302, 'http://google.com');
```

Instead of redirecting, this line displays in the browser:

`Found. Redirecting to http://google.com`

I have tried on Firefox and Chrome. There are no errors in the browser or in the terminal. I don't see any redirect config. Why is this happening when running locally?

Comment: Can you include the entire response you get back? To do that, run `curl` with the `-i` option. If you can't just run curl straight on the URL in question, the Chrome devtools allow right-clicking on the request and then `Copy -> Copy as curl`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I appreciate the help but don't have weekend access. As I edited in the text of the question, there is a service doing a POST to the endpoint that runs the function with the redirect in question.

Comment: What is a "service doing a POST".  Is that from a browser?  Is that a form post?  Or an Ajax call?  Or is that from some code somewhere outside of a browser?  I ask because there are only certain circumstances where a redirect response is automatically followed and the redirected content displayed.  We need to understand what exact this circumstance this is in order to advise on this topic.  In the future, if you're not going to have access for awhile, don't post then.  Post when you will have access for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `res` is the `express` response object, you could check couple of things:
1. Are there any errors on the browser console when you get the redirect response back?
2. Check for any external redirect config in your express config file(CORS ‍♂️). These are usually environment specific configs.

P.S. you can remove the 302 and just pass the URL to `redirect` function. Default is 302 if you are using express.

Comment: @Gautum I have updated the question -- no errors, and no redirect config.